# Mac OS Mavericks numpy Version Issue

Tags: python, macos, numpy

When I run 'pip freeze' it shows that numpy==1.8.1; however, when I start Python and import numpy and then check the version number via numpy.version.version I get 1.6.

This is confusing to me and it's also creating a problem for scipy and matplotlib. For example, when I attempt to do the following import 'from matplotlib import pyplot' I get an error saying 'RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6'. This I'm guessing has something to do with the numpy versions being wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does `which python` and `which pip` output from shell?

Comment: OS X has the nasty tendency to have two versions of Python at the same time. One is the Python coming with the OS, the other one is then something you have installed through macports, EPD, or something else. So Padraic's question is a very good one, as it reveals which one you really try to start. The /usr/bin/python one is Apple's standard python which is next to useless for numpy/scipy/matplotlib.

Comment: So which python returns '/usr/bin/python' and which pip returns '/usr/local/bin/pip'

Comment: and `which -a python`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: add `export path="/usr/local/bin:$path"` to `.bashrc` and enter `source .bashrc` in terminal after you save it  then try python shell again.

Comment: I don't have a .bashrc in my home directory. I'm assuming you want me to add that file?

Comment: yes, do you have `.zshrc`?

Comment: So I created .bashrc, ran 'source .bashrc', started python console and tried numpy.version.version: still get 1.6. No I do not have .zshrc.

Comment: what does `which python` show now?

Comment: what terminal shell are you using?

Comment: It's the default Mac one. Not sure what the actual name is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55611/discussion-between-przemek-lach-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our conversation in chat and adding path to .bashrc not working:

Putting:

`/usr/local/bin` first in `/etc/paths` will resolve the issue